# android getContentResolver() order issue

Tags: android

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEflC.png)
I am trying to getContentResolver in MyLocationListenerActivity for accessing the data base which is implemented as LogContentProvider here. I have registered the MyLocationListenerActivity to the locationManager in MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void trackingServiceButtonOnClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
    MyLocationListenerActivity.class));
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    MyLocationListenerActivity myLocationListener = new MyLocationListenerActivity();

    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, myLocationListener);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d("debug", e.toString());
    }
    if (getContentResolver() != null) {
        Log.d("debug", "I can get content resolver");
    }
}
```

and in MyLocationListenerActivity, If I want to getContentResolver() in onCreate(), that's fine, but If I try to getContentResolver in onLocationChanged, a error "get contentResolver() on a null object reference occurs", does anyone know why this happens?

```
public class MyLocationListenerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_location_listener);
        // test() works fine here
        test();
    }

    public void test() {
        getContentResolver();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // error will happen here
        test();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
```

Comment: `MyLocationListenerActivity myLocationListener = new MyLocationListenerActivity();` – You cannot directly instantiate an `Activity` yourself, and have it work correctly. Unless `MyLocationListenerActivity` is actually being used as an `Activity` – i.e., unless it actually appears on-screen itself – it should not extend any `Activity` class.

Comment: thanks Mike, I changed the code structure and it works!